# Why does my range show non-existent value in the slice?

Tags: go

I was trying to solve a Leetcode problem in Go. The problem is [subsets](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/).

This is the whole code I'm writing with some debug log:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v := []int{9, 0, 3, 5, 7}
    fmt.Println(subsets(v))
}

func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{
        []int{}, // empty
    }

    for _, num := range nums {  
        fmt.Println("==========")
        fmt.Println(num)
        fmt.Printf("result = %v\n", result)

        temp := [][]int{}
        for _, r := range result {
            fmt.Printf("r = %v\n", r)
            temp = append(temp, append(r, num))
        }

        for _, t := range temp {
            result = append(result, t)
        }

        fmt.Println("==========")       
    }

    return result
}
```

(I also prepared [Go play ground URL](https://play.golang.org/p/LijFtj7TdSf))

Here is the output of above code:

```
==========
9
result = [[]]
r = []
==========
==========
0
result = [[] [9]]
r = []
r = [9]
==========
==========
3
result = [[] [9] [0] [9 0]]
r = []
r = [9]
r = [0]
r = [9 0]
==========
==========
5
result = [[] [9] [0] [9 0] [3] [9 3] [0 3] [9 0 3]]
r = []
r = [9]
r = [0]
r = [9 0]
r = [3]
r = [9 3]
r = [0 3]
r = [9 0 3]
==========
==========
7
result = [[] [9] [0] [9 0] [3] [9 3] [0 3] [9 0 3] [5] [9 5] [0 5] [9 0 5] [3 5] [9 3 5] [0 3 5] [9 0 3 5]] // (a)
r = []
r = [9]
r = [0]
r = [9 0]
r = [3]
r = [9 3]
r = [0 3]
r = [9 0 3]
r = [5]
r = [9 5]
r = [0 5]
r = [9 0 5]
r = [3 5]
r = [9 3 5]
r = [0 3 5]
r = [9 0 3 7] // (b)
==========
[[] [9] [0] [9 0] [3] [9 3] [0 3] [9 0 3] [5] [9 5] [0 5] [9 0 5] [3 5] [9 3 5] [0 3 5] [9 0 3 7] [7] [9 7] [0 7] [9 0 7] [3 7] [9 3 7] [0 3 7] [9 0 3 7] [5 7] [9 5 7] [0 5 7] [9 0 5 7] [3 5 7] [9 3 5 7] [0 3 5 7] [9 0 3 7 7]]
```

Let's see 5th `result`. (I pointed out there as `(a)` ) As of there, the last element of `result` is `[9, 0, 3, 5]`, and this is expected behavior.
However, after that, when I'm trying to write a debug log of the element in `result`, it changes to `[9, 0, 3, 7]` ( `(b)` ).

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` changes the `r` when needed:
Instead of:

```
 temp = append(temp, append(r, num))
```

You may use:

```
            rr := make([]int, len(r))
            copy(rr, r)
            rr = append(rr, num)
            temp = append(temp, rr)
```

and you are good to go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v := []int{9, 0, 3, 5, 7}
    fmt.Println(subsets(v))
}

func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{
        []int{}, // empty
    }

    for _, num := range nums {
        fmt.Println("==========")
        fmt.Println(num)
        fmt.Printf("result = %v\n", result)

        temp := [][]int{}
        for _, r := range result {
            fmt.Printf("r = %v\n", r)
            // append(r, num)
            rr := make([]int, len(r))
            copy(rr, r)
            rr = append(rr, num)
            temp = append(temp, rr)
        }

        for _, t := range temp {
            result = append(result, t)
        }

        fmt.Println("==========")
    }

    return result
}
```

Just debug your code and you'll see, it happens here:

```
        temp := [][]int{}
        for _, r := range result {
            fmt.Println("result =", result, len(result), cap(result))
            fmt.Println("r ==", r, len(r), cap(r))
            fmt.Println("num =", num)
            rr := append(r, num)
            fmt.Println("r ==", r, len(r), cap(r))
            fmt.Println("rr ==", rr, len(rr), cap(rr))
            fmt.Println("result =", result, len(result), cap(result))
            fmt.Println("temp =", temp)
            temp = append(temp, rr)
            fmt.Println("temp =", temp)
        }
```

When

```
result = [[] [9] [0] [9 0] [3] [9 3] [0 3] [9 0 3] [5] [9 5] [0 5] [9 0 5] [3 5] [9 3 5] [0 3 5] [9 0 3 5]] 16 16
r == [9 0 3] 3 4
num = 7
r == [9 0 3] 3 4
rr == [9 0 3 7] 4 4
result = [[] [9] [0] [9 0] [3] [9 3] [0 3] [9 0 3] [5] [9 5] [0 5] [9 0 5] [3 5] [9 3 5] [0 3 5] [9 0 3 7]] 16 16
```

Because of:

```
 append(r, num)
```

Comment: And see  The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append)